# iPhone - Autorotation doesnt work after playing youtube video in other uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, youtube, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller, autorotate

I have a problem with autorotation of a viewcontroller (Inside a tabbarController, this is the only viewcontroller that should autorotate) and this works by setting the **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation** to just portrait in the AppDelegate and 
presenting the view that SHOULD autorotate as a modalViewcontroller and
setting  shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation in that viewcontroller to YES (=All)
This works fine, BUT: after i played a youtube video (in a different viewcontroller) and go back, IT STOPS WORKING! I checked everything, and the hierarchy etc, all seems the same but shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation doesnt get called anymore!
All help/suggestions really appriciated!! Thanks!!